# "How to Ask Questions in Private Beta" help page?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I just noticed in the help center that there's a page entitled [How to Ask Questions in Private Beta](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask-beta), under the "Asking" section.

Obviously, we are *looooong* out of private beta. Shouldn't this page either be removed or reworked into other help pages like [What topics can I ask about here?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) or [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) or [How do I ask a good question?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Obviously the bits about

> The first questions set the tone and topic of a site for a long time. Those early questions say a lot about what your community could become. And questions asked during the private beta will be on the front page when potential experts see your site for the first time. So please **make those first questions exemplary ones that are interesting, challenging, and worthy of imitation.**

are probably able to be removed entirely, but maybe

> #### Think like an expert
>
> Stick to actual, real, objective questions with concrete answers that a working professional or expert in this field might encounter as a part of their actual, real, job. Stock the site with a bunch of on-topic, expert questions and answers, so that when the site opens to the public, it’s already pre-populated with a bunch of the kind of content that will attract other experts.

can be worked into other help pages?

Comment: Yeah, that's baked into the help on every single site; here's the [Meta.SE request to fix that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/290401/162102).  It's even worse for us; Mi Yodeya never *had* a private beta!  The site went straight from SE 1.0 (public) to SE 2.0 public beta -- no need for a private step because there was an existing community and body of questions already.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342473/remove-how-to-ask-questions-in-private-beta-from-the-help-center https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3594/why-is-there-still-a-page-from-the-private-beta-in-the-help-center